# Problem with back button in my app

Tags: android, button, back

I want to clear shared preference values when my mobile is switched off?

Comment: Please improve your question, put some efforts else its going to be closed.

Comment: Re-asking the same question is considered abuse of the system; please don't do it.  If you can clarify your question by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7498418/edit), then please do so.  Once your question has been improved (see this section in the [faq#howtoask] to learn how), flag for moderator attention.  Select "other" and ask for a mod to reopen your question.

Answer (score 2):

How can you clear `SharedPreference` when the device is `switched off`.

You can clear it when the device starts thru `BraodcastReceiver`.

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            //Clear your `SharedPreference` here.
        }
    }
}
```

In your manifest add this:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.PhoneStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Asfar as i know the only possibility is to use `OnDestroy()` but your program should be running when the device is shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Same question as: Android: [Android: How to make a specific SharedPreference reset itself after the system reboots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939071/android-how-to-make-a-specific-sharedpreference-reset-itself-after-the-system-re)

I don't know of a different way. This implementation is quite simple. Just handle the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast action and clear preferences by calling .clear() on the SharedPreference.Editor ([answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630457/clearing-preferences-in-sharedpreferences-in-android-not-just-values)).

A simple Boot receiver might look like this:

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                      //clear preferences here         
                }

}
```

Declare it also in your AndroidManifest.xml as:

```
           <receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver">
                    <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

You will also need a permission for this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```