# Clearing Shared Preference when Mobile is switched off

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with back button in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498418/problem-with-back-button-in-my-app)

I want to clear the values in shared preference when i'll switch off my mobile

Please help

Comment: This question was just closed, please don't repost closed questions without improving them significantly. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498418/problem-with-back-button-in-my-app